# Best factory pattern for delivering app data object based on application type in http header

Tags: java, design-patterns, factory

I have a business with multiple applications using my webservice resource. I have a web service resource that looks in a http header for the application ID. This tell the server which application is requesting data.  My goal is to deliver to my web application developers a method they can call to retrieve all the application specific settings via the application ID. 
Given an applicationID i can specify device type, properties file for that app, and whether GCM,APNS or Microsoft Push Notification, etc. So each applicationID has distinct properties basically.

I want the developer to be able to call for this object like this (or similar):

```
ApplicationData appData = ApplicationDataFactory.getCurrentApplicationData();
```

and the factory would look something like this:

```
class ApplicationDataFactory
{
  public static ApplicationData getCurrentApplicationData()
  {

//notice how im not passing in criteria here, im getting it from the request so call doens't have to know
  String criteria = Request.getHTTPHeaderInfo("applicationID");

    if ( criteria.equals("Android") )
      return new Android();  

    else if ( criteria.equals("Android-germany") )
        return new Android_germany();

    else if ( criteria.equals("ios_germany") )
          return new ios_germany();

    else if ( criteria.equals("ios"))
      return new ios();

    else if ( criteria.equals("windows") )
      return new windows();

    return null;//or throw exception
  }
}
```

so Android, ios, and windows objects all extend off ApplicationData class clearly.

So for example the Android.java object would look like this:

```
class Android extends ApplicationData{

@override
public String getType(){
  return "Android"
}
  @override
public Properties getProperties{
    return system.getProperties("android.properties");

  }
}
```

and the Android-germany and ios-germany will have common data since there both from germany.

First, i  dont like that im specifying the criteria inside the factory and also can anyone help me
with a good design pattern i can use to achieve this ? Remember, in the end i want to be able to have the developer call only `ApplicationDataFactory.getCurrentApplicationData();` (or something similar) and the correct application info will be sent referenced. I dont have to use a factory here either its just the first thing i thought of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your problem is with the fact that the logic for the criteria is within the factory method. Meanwhile, you don't want the user to provide the criteria as an parameter to the factor method.

First of all, I don't like the idea of having a static `Request` class. A request should be an object that contains information about the current request. I have a suspicion that your code may be prone to race conditions, once you have many concurrent requests (how do you know which request is which?). So as a starting point, I would refactor the `Request` class so that you work with instances of `Request`.

I think, the clearest approach would be that you pass in `applicationID` as a parameter. This makes testability trivial and the code becomes very obvious, too. You take an input and produce the output based on the input. You could pass the `Request` instead of the `applicationID` and let the factory handle the retrieval of the `applicationID` from the request (as you are doing now).

If you think the `Request` -> `applicationID` logic should not be part of the factory, you can create another class, such as `ApplicationIDResolver` which translates a `Request` to an `applicationID`. From then on `ApplicationDataFactory` would be used through an instance and the `ApplicationIDResolver` would be a constructor parameter. (I think, this is an overkill.). Another option is to add a `getApplicationID()` method to the `Request` class.

If you use a dependency injection framework, it may take care of object life cycles/scopes automatically for you, so the `ApplicationData` could be a request-scoped object and you could tell your dependency injection framework to instantiate `ApplicationData` objects based on requests and inject them into the classes where they get used.

Comment: The DI part is exactly what i was looking for, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use for this purposes enum which implements ApplicationData interface and define each entry. You can resolve proper by valueOf() from enum.

Comment: show me final call ? how would developers call it ?